# r data.table - assign blank to duplicate value (by group)

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to make duplicate value blank by group (a,b,c) using data.table. I tried below but it only works on the variable. I was thinking of using tail() or head() as i but that didnt work.

```
df$E[duplicated(df$E)] <- ""
```

**Input Table**

```
a,b,c
=====
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,2,1
1,2,2
1,3,1
1,3,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,2,1
2,2,2
2,3,1
2,3,2
```

**Expected Output Table**

```
a,b,c
=====
1,1,1
 , ,2
 ,2,1
 , ,2
 ,3,1
 , ,2
2,1,1
 , ,2
 ,2,1
 , ,2
 ,3,1
 , ,2
```

Comment: Are you doing this for display purposes? Or do you need the data in this form for some kind of analysis? Are empty spaces `NA` or are you planning on converting the first two columns to `character`?

Comment: it is for display purposes. I am converting NA to character but need to consider type of column as I might have numeric column too.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `tables` package if it's for display purposes. Not in front of a computer at the moment, so can't pull up an example right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~a,~b,~c,
  1,1,1,
  1,1,2,
  1,2,1,
  1,2,2,
  1,3,1,
  1,3,2,
  2,1,1,
  2,1,2,
  2,2,1,
  2,2,2,
  2,3,1,
  2,3,2

         ) %>% as.data.table()

df[,dupa:=rleid(a)][,rowid :=seq_len(.N) ,by=dupa][,a:=ifelse(rowid>1,NA,a)][,c("dupa","rowid"):=.(NULL,NULL)]
df[,dupb:=rleid(b)][,rowid :=seq_len(.N) ,by=dupb][,b:=ifelse(rowid>1,NA,b)][,c("dupb","rowid"):=.(NULL,NULL)]
df[,dupc:=rleid(c)][,rowid :=seq_len(.N) ,by=dupc][,b:=ifelse(rowid>1,NA,c)][,c("dupc","rowid"):=.(NULL,NULL)]
df
     a  b c
 1:  1  1 1
 2: NA NA 2
 3: NA  2 1
 4: NA NA 2
 5: NA  3 1
 6: NA NA 2
 7:  2  1 1
 8: NA NA 2
 9: NA  2 1
10: NA NA 2
11: NA  3 1
12: NA NA 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is intended for display purposes, I would suggest looking at the `tables` package. It's a very comprehensive and powerful package (which also means that there's a bit of a learning curve) and I suggest you [look at the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) to get started.

Here's an example with data like yours:

```
tabular(Factor(a) * Factor(b) * AllObs(df) ~ c, data = df)
##       
##  a b c
##  1 1 1
##      2
##    2 1
##      2
##    3 1
##      2
##  2 1 1
##      2
##    2 1
##      2
##    3 1
##      2
##      3
```

Furthermore, you can convert this to latex using:

```
toLatex(tabular(Factor(a) * Factor(b) * AllObs(df) ~ c, data = df))
## \begin{tabular}{llc}
## \hline
## a & b & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} \\ 
## \hline
## 1 & 1  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
##  & 2  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
##  & 3  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
## 2 & 1  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
##  & 2  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
##  & 3  & $1$ \\
##  &   & $2$ \\
##  &   & $3$ \\
## \hline 
## \end{tabular}
```

When rendered, you get:

[image]

Here's the sample data used for this answer:

```
df <- structure(list(
   a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
   b = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
   c = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)), 
   row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thanks, I need to perform data processing before feeding it for display.

Comment: @R007, please read through the `tables` vignette. It can also handle data processing.

Comment: I only needed a solution for data.table as stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my new answer with a better understanding of the output

```
replace(df,rbind(1,apply(df,2,diff))==0,"")

    a b c
 1: 1 1 1
 2:     2
 3:   2 1
 4:     2
 5:   3 1
 6:     2
 7: 2 1 1
 8:     2
 9:   2 1
10:     2
11:   3 1
12:     2
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), b = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), c = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: output is the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `by`:

```
cols <- names(DT)
for (x in rev(names(DT))) {
    cols <- setdiff(cols, x)
    DT[, (x) := {
        v <- get(x)
        replace(v, duplicated(v), NA_integer_)
    }, cols]
}
```

data:

```
DT <- fread("a,b,c
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,2,1
1,2,2
1,3,1
1,3,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,2,1
2,2,2
2,3,1
2,3,2")
```